# How is '누워잠' composed of?

Tags: word-origin

누워잠 - to sleep

I think this word is a compound word.

누이다 - 자다

According to my text book, the last ㅁ changes 용언 to 명사.

누이다 자다 , both are related with sleeping.

I understand 자다 becomes 잠.

But　why is 누이다 changed to 누워?

누이으ㄴ잠?

누워잠 does not exist in my dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

누워 comes from 눕다, not 누이다.
ㅂ in 눕 is changed to 우 when followed by ㅓ. (Search for 'ㅂ irregular verbs' for this grammar. Other examples are here. https://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%E3%85%82_irregular_verbs)
눕+어 => 누워